# rules for circle circumscribing

Tags: circles

how can i determine wether a circle can be circumscribed about a quadrilateral?

Comment: Look at opposite angles. A convex quadrilateral is cyclic if and only if its opposite angles add up to $\pi$ ($= 180^\circ$).

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_quadrilateral

Answer (score 4):

If you're given a convex quadrilateral, a circle can be circumscribed about it if and only the quadrilateral is cyclic. A nice fact about cyclic quadrilaterals is that their opposite angles are supplementary.

[Proposition III.22](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookIII/propIII22.html) of Euclid's Elements gives a proof that the opposite angles of cyclic quadrilaterals are equal to two right angles. The converse is also true, that if the opposite angles of a quadrilateral are supplementary, then the quadrilateral is cyclic.

Another way to identify if a quadrilateral is cyclic is given in Hartshorne's book on classical geometry. A nice proof can be find in Hartshorne's Euclid: Geometry and Beyond, which I will include here.

[image]
[image]

If you can determine either of these facts hold about your quadrilateral, then you know there exists a possible circle circumscribed about it.